# How to get the sum of hour, minutes, and seconds in 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server as database. I have 2 columns in a table, `newTime, oldTime`.

Suppose I have value of `04:07:28` in the `newTime` column, and for `oldTime`, the value is `03:07:40`.

The result should get the total of `newTime` and `oldTime` columns which is `07:15:08`.

I tried the `Split_String()` function to easily split the numbers into hours, minutes, and seconds. But I have an issue in database the compatibility level is low and also I tried to set the `compatibility_level` to 130 but I don't have permission to alter the database.

Is there any other way to sum up the two columns? Thank you!

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please also tag the SQL Server version that you are using

Comment: What **datatype** are those columns?

Comment: @marc_s `VARCHAR`

Comment: And **WHY** are you storing **time values** in a string?? Use `TIME` !! That's what it's there for!

Comment: What result do you want if the total is above 24 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments - if you're storing **time values**, you should **really** be using the `TIME` datatype - not a `VARCHAR` ..... **always** use the **most appropriate** datatype - no exceptions.

Anyway - since you have `VARCHAR`, the statement get a bit convoluted - but here you go:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, CAST(NewTime AS TIME)), CAST(OldTime AS TIME)) 
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
```

which would look a lot easier with `TIME` columns, of course:

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, NewTime), OldTime) 
FROM 
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
```